# AppleScript to Burn a Single Data File to a CD

Tags: applescript

I need a/the AppleScript (not automator) command(s) that will burn a single PDF file (stored as a POSIX path) to a CD with a specified Disc Name (also stored in an AppleScript variable).

Today … I `right click` on a PDF file (**mySpecial.pdf**) in Finder and click `Burn "mySpecial.pdf" to Disc…` I then provide the name/title for the disc "Jimbo’s Special Disc" and click on `Burn`.

Thank you @matt.  I did try `drutil` before posting my question.  When I try this …

**`drutil burn ./test.PDF`**

I get the following:

**`Burning Image to Disc: ./test.pdf`**

**`Must specify a valid unmounted image path (dmg, iso, cue/bin, and toc).`**

Everything I’ve found so far seems to only refer to entire directories/folders or **image** file, not plain old **data** files.

Comment: `man drutil`. I suspect you would just be doing a `do script` on this.

Comment: @matt Thanks … please see my edits above.